# Помогите с setCustomAnimations

Tags: android, java

Помогите с кодом. По нажатию на один из onListItemClick открывается фрагмент с аниматион эффектом:

```
Css_page1 f1 = new Css_page1();
FragmentTransaction ft1= getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim);
ft1.add(R.id.listview_css, f1);
ft1.addToBackStack(null);
ft1.commit();
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии программной кнопки НАЗАД закрывался этот фрагмент с аниматион эффектом и открывался предыдущий фрагмент ListView (короче, наоборот)?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int, int, int, int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ сам:

```
Css_page1 f1 = new Css_page1();
FragmentTransaction ft1= getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim, R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim);
ft1.add(R.id.listview_css, f1);
ft1.addToBackStack(null);
ft1.commit();
```